# Using stored procedures in Symfony - pros and cons

Tags: php, stored-procedures, symfony1, doctrine

I'm writing a web application in Symfony for the first time, so I have a question regarding the use of Doctrine vs. Stored Procedures.

My background is in Java server-side, so I wanted to know what the pros and cons are for using stored procedures, versus using simple Doctrine code to get things done. At the most basic level, let's say that my Symfony web application is used for management, while there's another engine (which might or might not be written as a Symfony component, or indeed not in PHP at all) which retrieves configurations from the database for distribution or whatnot. Here I can see where stored procedures might be handy: both code bases use them to query and access data, while neither are preoccupied with the actual schema. If there's a change to the schema (adding a column in some table, for instance), then I'd only have to change the SRPOC, and nothing else, whereas if I had been using code in both engines to access data, I'd have to change them both to match the new schema.

Any comments? Or did I take it too far?

Thanks!
-DBG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use doctrine, you loose database abstraction, and object mapping. And this is a major loss. If you need third party apps integrations, you shouldn't let them interact with your database. Rather, provide a web service for them to read/write data via JSON, for example. This way you can change your database schema and have control over third-party apps.

Comment: ok, that's fair enough. Didn't think of it that - so the Symfony/Doctrine objects that I write will be the only interface to the database.. cool! thanks..